# Adjacent Windows outlook c#

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto, outlook-restapi

IHello, 
I want to make an [adjacent to the preview pane](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982758) Custom panes in **C#**. After searching i found [A post were someone want the same thinks](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bac3b1b5-01fc-42c3-8872-662cf4330c37/how-to-customise-the-folder-view-in-outlook-2010?forum=outlookdev). They end up with Hook. I have post this topic on MSDN (social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/607f9d9c-8f10-4eb7-8597-0a75e0179734/custom-task-panel-in-reading-pane-and-active-inline-response-22-with-adjacent-windows-in-c?forum=vsto). I have seen so many post about this problem bu no answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still search for explaination... Please.

Comment: still search for explaination

Comment: I make an User.dll wrapper

Comment: The only way to do that is to make is own c# version who is nearly impossible for a single and c++ beginner like me... If one days someone want to make a tools...

Answer (score 0):

See [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) sample project. You are free to use any programming languages since you can use Windows API functions.

Comment: How by translation each line into c#? Sorry maybe it use a c# feature i never used before?

Comment: I spend hour to try translating this C++ sample without any result. What should i use wrapper ?

Comment: Hi have looking for WindowInteropHelper and Hook.did i get closer?